# Display custom order meta in order received page and notification emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973267/display-order-custom-fields-on-woocommerce-order-received-page-and-emails) on how to display custom order meta into the order received page and into the notifications email of woocommerce. I've tried to do the same by refactoring the code but I'm unable to accomplish it correctly. In my case I have only three custom informations stored in product meta to display, how I need to fix the code?

```php
    // Display order custom meta data in Order received (thankyou) page
    public function display_order_custom_meta( $order_id ) {

        $fields_labels = array(  
            'selected_pdv',
            'selected_date',
            'selected_hour'
        );
        
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $count = 1;

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            // Loop through item quantity
            for($i = 1; $i <= $item->get_quantity(); $i++ ) {
                echo '<h6> '.$i . '</h6>';
                echo '<table><tbody>';
                // Loop through participants keys / labels pairs
                foreach( $fields_labels as $label ){
                    $meta_key = $label;
                    echo '<tr><th>'.$label.':</th><td>'.$order->get_meta( $meta_key ).'</td></tr>';
                }
                //
                echo '</tbody></table>';
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'display_order_custom_meta') )
```

Comment: Does order meta need to be displayed, or product meta need to be displayed?

Comment: I need to display order meta into the thank you page of woocommerce and into the email that the admin and the user will get when the order status is changed to complete

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Have you checked answer provided below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to provided code, to implement required functionality of displaying woocommerce order custom meta fields on "order received" page, woocomerce order emails, the following code can be checked:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_thankyou');
function custom_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    $fields_labels = array(  
        'selected_pdv',
        'selected_date',
        'selected_hour'
    );
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    echo '<table><tbody>';
    foreach( $fields_labels as $label ){
        echo '<tr><th>'.$label.':</th><td>'.$order->get_meta( $label ).'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_details', 10, 4 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $fields_labels = array(  
        'selected_pdv',
        'selected_date',
        'selected_hour'
    );
    $html_output = '<div>
    <table><tbody>';
    foreach( $fields_labels as $label ){
        $html_output .= '<tr><th>'.$label.':</th><td>'.$order->get_meta( $label ).'</td></tr>';
    }
    $html_output .= '</tbody></table></div>';
    echo $html_output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing the code and works as expected.